# How to animate a sine curve in PStricks/Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, animations

I would like to know how to set up an animations which consists of two "sub-animations" side by side or above/below, wherein one animation just shows a real number line from say zero to 2 pi one and the number line is coloured in as we move from zero to one. Simultaneously, the other animation will show the plot of sine(number) where the number is as far as we are on the number line. Hence at the end of the animation the plot of a full period of a sine wave will be shown.

Comment: Starting point: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/sine-and-cosine-functions-animation/

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea where yoiu really want to print the value of the sin curve. However, here is an example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}
\def\TINY{\fontsize{2pt}{2.1pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
  %-------------------- write timeline file ---------------------%
  \newwrite\TimeLineFile
  \immediate\openout\TimeLineFile=sinus.txt
  \immediate\write\TimeLineFile{::0x0,1}%
  \multido{\i=1+1}{37}{\immediate\write\TimeLineFile{::\i}}
  \immediate\closeout\TimeLineFile
  %------------------- assemble animation -----------------------%
  \psset{xunit=\pstRadUnit,yunit=1.5,dashadjust=false}
  \begin{animateinline}[controls,timeline=sinus.txt,
    begin={\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5)(6.6,2)},
    end={\end{pspicture}}]{3}
    %---- static material: axes, labels, curve ----%
    \psaxes[trigLabels,trigLabelBase=3]{->}(0,0)(-2mm,-1.5)(6.5,1.5)[t,-90][$y=\sin(t)$,0]
    \psplot[xunit=1cm,linestyle=dashed,algebraic]{0}{\psPiTwo}{sin(x)}
    \newframe
    \multiframe{37}{r=0+0.174444,i=0+1}{\psset{xunit=1cm,linecolor=red}
      \pscustom[xunit=1cm,fillcolor=red!30,fillstyle=solid,
        linestyle=none,algebraic,dimen=inner]{%
        \psplot{0}{\r}{sin(x)}
        \psline(!\r\space 0)
      }
      \psplot[xunit=1cm,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=black,
         algebraic]{0}{\r}{sin(x)}
      \psdot[opacity=0.4,dotsize=3mm](!\r\space dup exch RadtoDeg sin)
      \psline[linestyle=dashed](!\r\space dup exch RadtoDeg sin)(!\r\space 0)
      \multido{\rA=0+0.174444}{\i}{\rput[lc](!-1.5 \rA\space RadtoDeg sin){\makebox[1cm][l]{\TINY\rA}}}
      \rput[lc](!-1.5 \r\space  RadtoDeg sin){\makebox[1cm][l]{\textcolor{red}{\TINY\r}}}%
    }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

View it with the acrobat reader in full screen mode. The animated PDF is available from http://perce.de/pub/animate_sin.pdf

[image]

Comment: Dear Herbert, this example works well in TL2103, but does not work in TL2014 and TL2015; sin curve and axis are not displayed! Do you know why?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: I tested on Win7 32 bit and Win8.1 64 bit