# Animation in Beamer using ggb files

Tags: beamer, animations

Can I use `beamer` to display animations created by GeoGebra? GeoGebra can export Graphics to PGF/TikZ.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}
\definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1.,0.,0.}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (-1.097777777777778,0.) -- (6.4044444444444455,0.);
\foreach \x in {-1.,-0.5,0.5,1.,1.5,2.,2.5,3.,3.5,4.,4.5,5.,5.5,6.}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0.,-2.0044444444444456) -- (0.,2.1555555555555586);
\foreach \y in {-2.,-1.5,-1.,-0.5,0.5,1.,1.5,2.}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(-1.097777777777778,-2.0044444444444456) rectangle (6.4044444444444455,2.1555555555555586);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (0.,0.) circle (1.cm);
\draw [domain=-0.00:6.2918,color=ffqqqq] plot(\x,{sin(\x*360/6.2918)});
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,color=qqqqff] (0.9427546655283462,0.3334870921408144)-- (0.34,0.3334870921408144);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.9427546655283462,0.3334870921408144) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (1.0088888888888892,0.4577777777777792) node {$P$};
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.34,0.3334870921408144) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (0.40444444444444455,0.4577777777777792) node {$Q$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I can't because I don't know how to start.

Comment: How about creating a simple animation in GeoGebra and show us what the exported tikz file looks like?

Comment: This is a still from such an animation:

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to add the code and ran out of time. When I try to add the code here I am told that I have too many characters. How can I add it?

Comment: Please use the edit button of your question. And have a look at [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192)

Comment: Thanks.
This file is exported by GeoGebra as PGF/TikZ but GeoGebra can produce an animation showing the points moving around the circle and on the sin graph. My query is about animating this process as a series of slides in beamer.

Comment: This http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sine-and-cosine-functions-animation/ could be of interest.

Comment: Or even closer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206936/how-to-animate-a-sine-curve-in-pstricks-tikz

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work on my MacBook with Sierra. It just displays as a single image with Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: It works on 10.9 with TeXLive2016 :( From another question on this site I gathered that geogebra can export the animation to .gif?

Comment: You don't speak German by chance? There is a guide how to do this via .gif http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7875/kann-ich-eine-interaktive-geogebra-datei-in-ein-latex-beamer-dokument-einbinden

Comment: No. I don't speak German but if I could use an animated gif that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following text is summarized from http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7875/kann-ich-eine-interaktive-geogebra-datei-in-ein-latex-beamer-dokument-einbinden

@HenriMenke In case you would like to answer this question yourself, I will happily delete this

---

1. Save you animation as an animated gif, see https://www.geogebra.org/manual/en/Export_to_LaTeX_%28PGF,_PSTricks%29_and_Asymptote#Export_-_Graphics_View_as_Animated_GIF for a tutorial
2. Divide this .gif into individual frames. You can use the following command line expression to do this:

   ```
   convert -density 100 animate.gif animate-%d.pdf
   ```

   This will result in individual files, named animate-0.pdf to e.g. animate-200.pdf
3. To animate these files in beamer:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{animate}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
     \animategraphics[
     autoplay,loop,
     width=.7\textwidth,
     height=.7\textheight
     ]{10}{animate/animate-}{0}{200}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```
4. Use adobe reader (or another viewer capable of javascript) to view the pdf.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort. I can convert to pdf but it won't animate. I am using beamer on a Mac using 10.12 and TeXShop 3.73 and will be giving an online tutorial using BigBlueButton to postgrads so I reckon that I will just have to prepare slides and click swiftly through them!